# $_FILES['uploadImg']['name'] can't be found after clicked on submit button

Tags: php, file, post, file-upload, upload

I want to upload img from my computer to my website. When I click on the input type "file" I can add img and I can see its name. But when I click on upload "please add image" display.

```
if (!empty($_POST["uploadImg"])) {
 echo "button was clicked! " 
if (!empty($_FILES['profileImg']['name'])) {
  echo "it works!!!";
} else {
    echo "please add image";
}}
```

HTML:

```
    <form method="post" action="" class="edit_profile">           
    <!-- profielfoto -->
    <img src="<?php echo "none"; //$profile[1]['image_name'] 
                ?>" alt="Profielfoto">
    <input type="file" name="profileImg" id="profileImg" class="new_avatar" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg">
    <!--button-->
    <input type="submit" name="uploadImg" class="btn" value="Upload Image">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<form method="post" action="" class="edit_profile">
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="" class="edit_profile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```